# Trusting p-values when errors are not normally distributed

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Suppose I have a multiple linear regression model and the errors are not distributed normally.Does the central limit theorem hold true in this case? should i trust the p values of the coefficients of variables assuming the residuals are not skewed?

Will really appreciate any help on this, thank you :)

Comment: Did you test for heteroscedasticity? If there is heteroscedasticity, use robust SEs. Also see this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/73509/71442